# Getting remaining space in boost's stream<array_source>

Tags: c++, boost

I made a class derived from boost::iostreams::stream< boost::iostreams::array_source > in order to extract binary values using the >> operator.

Everything works fine. I'm at the point where I wish to offer a boolean method called hasRoomFor(n) in order to indicate if the internal stream buffer contains enough characters for the next value(s) to extract.

But I'm not able to do it via rdbuf(). Although it returns a valid pointer, the in_avail() always return 0.

I checked with a debugger and the usual istream`s beg, cur and end pointers are all 0.
However I can see an attribute called member (of type stream_buffer) under which I see the equivalent for beg and end only.

I can't figure out a way to know where is the current pointer within the buffer. Having this info would help me determine the remaining space.

I could still count the characters extracted by the methods of my class but if the user calls the istream methods directly (which are not virtual) I will miss some; thus not reliable.

Does any one would have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: "I have made a class derived from stream" - _fascinating_. It's a shame we can only guess what it looks like, and _what_ `stream` you are talking about, e.g..

Comment: Sorry for the hard guessing, but I realized that if one does not leave a space between < and >, then it is assumed a html tag, and becomes invisible.